# How to remove undefined properties from object

Tags: typescript

How could I remove all undefined properties from object?

In other words, convert this:

```
{
  a: 'asd'
  b: undefined
}
```

Into this:

```
{
  a: 'asd'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over keys and delete if the property value is `undefined` using [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```js
let data = {
  a: 'asd',
  b: undefined
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
  if (data[k] === undefined) delete data[k];
})

// or one liner
// Object.keys(data).forEach(k => data[k] === undefined && delete data[k])

console.log(data);
```

or using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterator.

```js
let data = {
  a: 'asd',
  b: undefined
}

for(let k in data){
  if (data[k] === undefined) delete data[k];
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop for Object key and remove by delete method.

```js
let obj = {
  a: 'asd',
  b: undefined
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');

console.log(obj)
```